How do I change Nural function 1.X Tensorflow to 2.X Tensorflow?
layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w_1), b_1))
layer_1_b = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer_1)
layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1_b, w_2), b_2))
layer_2_b = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer_2)
layer_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2_b, w_3), b_3))
layer_3_b = tf.layers.batch_normalization(layer_3)
y = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_3, w_4), b_4))
g_q_action = tf.argmax(y, axis=1)

# compute loss
g_target_q_t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, None, name="target_value")
g_action = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, None, name='g_action')
action_one_hot = tf.one_hot(g_action, n_output, 1.0, 0.0, name='action_one_hot')
q_acted = tf.reduce_sum(y * action_one_hot, reduction_indices=1, name='q_acted')

g_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(g_target_q_t - q_acted), name='g_loss')
optim = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.95, epsilon=0.01).minimize(g_loss)

Error statement:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\T\PycharmProjects\Project1\.venv\main_test.py", line 139, in <module>
    layer_1 = tf.compat.v1.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, w_1), b_1))
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\weak_tensor_ops.py", line 142, in wrapper
    return op(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1037, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(e.message)

To change 1.x to 2.x Tensorflow.

You could switch to TensorFlow v2 and use the function tf.compat.v1.placeholder, however, as said in the documentation try to use tf.Keras.Input instead migrating all code to v2.
